# How big can a GKE container image get before it's a problem?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This question is admittedly somewhat vague. If you have suggestions how to better word it, please by all means, give me feedback...

I want to understand how big a GKE container image can get before there may be problems, either serious or minor. For example, I've built a docker image (not deployed yet) that is 683 MB.

*(As an aside, the reason it's so big is that I'm running a computer vision library licensed from a company with certain attributes: (1) uses native libraries that are not compatible with Alpine; (2) uses Java; (3) uses Node.js to run a required licensing daemon in same container; (4) has some very large machine learning model files.)*

Although the service will have auto-scaling enabled, I expect the auto-scaling to be fairly light. It might add a new pod occasionally, but not major spikes up and down.

Comment: Depends what you mean by problem. GKE worker nodes will need to download the container images, so if the image is bigger than the available disk for the node, that will be a show-stopping problem. You could always try to create worker nodes with bigger and bigger disk. It could also take unreasonably long to download the image, depends on how long is too long for you. If you have autoscaling and K8s decides to start a pod on a worker that hasn't cached that image yet, it'll need to download it, so autoscaling may be slow, but how slow do you consider it to be a problem?

Comment: What is causing your image to be so large? You can search for some best practices for creating small images, like using multi-stage builds. See more [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/). You could consider distributing your ML model files a different way, like putting them in a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs) and mounting them into your pod via a PersistentVolumeClaim.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the container will determine how many resources to assign it and thus how much CPU, memory and disk space your nodes.must have. I have seen containers require over 2 GB of memory and still work fine within the cluster.

There probably is an upper limit but the containers would have to be enormous, your container size should not pose any issues aside from possibly container startup

Comment: The question is about the (disk) size of the image, not the memory allocated to the container process.

Comment: And that was also answered, use larger boot disks for.the larger image. Regardless of the size of the image, allocate more resources to the node. GKE defaults to 100GB, but you can assign  up to 2TB

Answer (score 0):

In practice, you're going to have issues pushing an image to GCR before you have issues running it on GKE, but there isn't a hard limit outside the storage capabilities of your nodes. You can get away with O(GB) pretty easily.